# Log4j conflicts- container provided and project level

Tags: maven, exception, tomcat, grails, log4j

We got a couple of grails applications running, each with its own Log4j classes. 
They need to be moved with a server that has log4j provided by Tomcat.

It it possible to get the grails applications to use the tomcat provided libraries?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try excluding log4j from Grails depencies so that Tomcat provided log4j will be used:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
        excludes "log4j"
    }
}
```